# Prove/Disprove that ideal $\langle xy-z^7\rangle$ and $\langle xy,yz,zx\rangle$ are primary

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

I need to check whether the ideals $\langle xy-z^7\rangle$  and $\langle xy,yz,zx\rangle$ in the ring $K[x,y,z]$ primary or not ($K$ is a field)

The only tool I know at the moment is that an Ideal is primary if the corresponding radical is a maximal ideal

But how do I compute the radical for each of these ideals

Any help?

Comment: That tool is useful, but I don't believe there's a way to use it to show an ideal _isn't_ primary.  I'd go back to the definition for at least one of them.  For instance, can you show that $x^n \not\in \langle xy, yz, zx\rangle$ for every integer $n>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial $xy-z^7$ is irreducible. (Hint: Eisenstein's criterion.) Therefore $\langle xy-z^7\rangle$ is a prime ideal of $K[x,y,z]$. Any prime ideal is primary.

The comments to your question have dealt with $\langle xy,yz,zx\rangle$.